# IOS7 Singleton Object Bad Access Code 1

Tags: objective-c, object, singleton, exc-bad-access, ios7

(CODE UPDATED)  after IOS 7 update, my app is crashing with singleton label (and this happened only in the device)...first time accessing singleton everything it's ok, but second time ClassSingleton is nil. Can anyone help? (before IOS 7 everything was fine...now i get Bad Access Code =1)

I'm using ARC...

thanks

### ClassSingleton.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *lblResultado;
```

### ClassSingleton.m

```
@synthesize lblResultado;


__strong static ClassSingleton *pOutClassSingletonReturn = nil;



#pragma mark Singleton Methods


+ (void)initialize
{
        pOutClassSingletonReturn = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];

        pOutClassSingletonReturn.lblResultado = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        pOutClassSingletonReturn.lblResultado.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        pOutClassSingletonReturn.lblResultado.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        pOutClassSingletonReturn.lblResultado.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

        pOutClassSingletonReturn.lblResultado.text = @"0";
}



+ (ClassSingleton*) pOutClassSingletonReturn
{
    return pOutClassSingletonReturn;
}

@end
```

### AccessClass.m

```
@implementation AccessClass

__strong static ClassSingleton *pOutClassSingletonReturn;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    externalsObjects = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[ClassSingleton  pOutClassSingletonReturn] forKey:@"pOutClassSingletonReturn"];


    nibOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:externalsObjects forKey:UINibExternalObjects];

    [self.nibBundle loadNibNamed:self.nibName owner:self options:nibOptions];

    pOutClassSingletonReturn = [ClassSingleton pOutClassSingletonReturn];

    pOutClassSingletonReturn.lblResultado.text = @"1";
}


- (IBAction) button: (id) sender

{
     pOutClassSingletonReturn.lblResultado.text = @"blabla";  //==>>> Crash second time i press the button
}
```

Comment: The idea of making a singleton UILabel seems a little weird to me, but I assume you have a reason for it. You must be adding the label as a subview to some view. Presumably, when the view is removed, it removes the label. The second time you attempt to get your singleton, the dispatch_once block doesn't fire again and so you get the null reference. Perhaps if you could post more details about what you are trying to accomplish, somebody could suggest a better approach.

Comment: The label changes to "blabla" ever time i press a button (and the second time a press button, i get a bad access because singleton is nil), like that: - (IBAction) button: (id) sender

{
     pOutClassSingletonReturn.lblResultado.text = @"blabla";
}

Answer (score 3):

You implemented the singleton pattern improperly in modern Objective-C.

In this example, let's call your Singleton class method, `sharedInstance`. Initialize your singleton as follows:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static id sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Then, in the same Singleton Class, put your initialization code in your `init` method

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        // Your initialization code goes here

    }
    return self;
}
```

You can change the method from `init` to whatever you want. Just make sure to change the name in the `sharedInstance` class method.

To call your Singleton in your other classes, simply do the following:

`[MySingletonClass sharedInstance]`

The first time it's called, the `init` method in the Singleton will be set (which is obvious, as it's a Singleton).

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing your singleton using the static `+ (void)initialize` method instead.

See: [What should my Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like)

Comment: i did like you said and continues crashing

    + (void)initialize
    {
        static BOOL initialized = NO;
        if(!initialized)
        {
            initialized = YES;
            pOutClassSingletonReturn = [[ClassSingleton alloc] init];
       }
   }

Comment: Bummer. Same crash? BTW the static `initialize` method is guaranteed to be called only once when a class object is created. Therefore you don't need the `if(!initialized)` logic, it doesn't harm anything its just not needed.

Comment: yes, same crash. First time accessing singleton everything ok, then second time bad access (singleton is nil). Any ideas? i don't understand why only in IOS7 and why only in the device...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you've declared `pOutClassSingletonReturn` in AccessClass.m, so it's hard to tell if it's a global variable, an instance variable, a reference to the `pOutClassSingletonReturn` in ClassSingleton.m, or what. But I suspect that the problem isn't so much with the `pOutClassSingletonReturn` in ClassSingleton.m as it is with the one in AccessClass.m. Make sure that's a strong reference, or at least add it to your view hierarchy in `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: update my code...for pOutClassSingletonReturn, please see the code (thanks for your help)

Answer (score 0):

First i want to thanks to everyone who try to help!

I found the error (singleton was ok...)...the error was

when i concatenate 2 NSString's like that i get an error (further in the singleton):

```
pOutclassCalculadora.pstrOutParcela1 = [pOutclassCalculadora.pstrOutParcela1 stringByAppendingString: pOutclassCalculadora.pstrOutTeclaSender];
```

Now i'm doing like that and everything is ok (no bad access):

```
pOutclassCalculadora.pstrOutParcela1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",pOutclassCalculadora.pstrOutParcela1,pOutclassCalculadora.pstrOutTeclaSender];
```

The big question...why this "stringByAppendingString" works in the simulator and in IO6 and crashes in IOS7 (and only in the device)?????

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ARC then try declaring the static to be strong like this:

`__strong static ClassSingleton *pOutClassSingletonReturn = nil;`

so that ARC knows to retain it for you.

Comment: With __strong same thing...crashes...I tried with instruments ("profile") simulation in the DEVICE and did Ok. But when i use "run" to simulate in device crashes again. Is this a IOS7 Bug?? my app is crashing and i can not see how i'm going resolve this issue :(

Comment: I use singletons in iOS 7 and none of my singletons are problematic for me. Have you tried turning on Zombies?

Comment: I am glad you got it working but why did you down vote my answer?

Comment: Not me...i can not down vote or vote up, because i don't have "reputation"